# Save file from HTTP response

Tags: wso2-esb

Looking for some guidance or pointers, not necessarily the solution however I will post a solution back when done.

Using WSO2 ESB / Integrator that is calling an external service. According to the external service [1], they will respond with a file back in the HTTP response. It is this file that I am after; both to save the binary to disk and send to a user via web page redirect.

Can anybody point me in a direction in which I can take the HTTP response and create a file? I am presuming that I need to transform the response and use VFS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[1] - https://support.webmerge.me/hc/en-us/articles/206526216-Webhook

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straight forward, the first step is to enable the transport sender for VFS (and the receiver if you also want to read files) in de axis2.xml config file. 
The lines are already there and just need to be uncommented.

```
<transportReceiver name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener"/>

<transportSender name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender"/>
```

Next you will need to transform your response to whatever format you want to write to the file. You could use an xslt transformation, payload mediator or datamapper mediator for example.

After that you simple send the payload to a vfs endpoint. This can be a local file location, or a remote ftp location for example. Make sure you have the correct privileges to write a file in said location. For example if you run your esb as WSO2 user, and want to write files to /opt/wso2/fileexchange, make sure the WSO2 user has write privileges on that folder.

Then to write to that location just use a send mediator like this:

```
<property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" value="myFile.txt" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint name="FileEpr">
            <address uri="vfs:file:///opt/wso2/fileexchange"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
```

Make sure to set the transport.vfs.ReplyFileName property to the filename you want to write. And the OUT_ONLY property, since the filesystem is not going to send a nice reply back to you.

For more on this subject you can always check [this blog](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-i-like-to-move-it-moving-files-with-wso2-esb-vfs-transport-part-1)

Comment: This is very helpful and I believe, very much in line with what I am looking for. The source link from my question mentions the "document is the HTTP response" so I will start to see how to map the response to VFS.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer send the URI which refer to the file instead of sending the binary data. So the more efficient way is upload the file to a FileSystem, then transfer it with a `String`(URI). Only when you need read the file's data, then download it from FileSystem. And you should ensure the network is OK between FileSystem and the final user.